# Unable to load data in hibernate mapping

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I'm working on online exam project by using **Struts Spring and Hibernate integration** with mysql & Eclipse kepler.
While submitting the values in registration.jsp page, i'm trying to store that values in two different tables (user_details,address) within the same database. I can able to store them in DB, but i can't able to fetch the user_id which is a foreign key for address table. user_id is the primary key in user_details table.Except user_id in address table, all the other fields are filled with the correct values. I'm trying to use that in address table. But i can't do that. I have attached the code that i'm using right now,

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="UserDetails" table="user_details">
        <id name="user_id" type="int" column="user_id" >
            <generator class="identity">

            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="first_name" type="string">
            <column name="first_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="last_name" type="string">
            <column name="last_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password"/>
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender"/>
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="int">
            <column name="dob"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="int">
            <column name="phone"/>
        </property>
        <property name="experience" type="float">
            <column name="experience"/>
        </property>

         <set name="addr" table="address"  
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade = "save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="user_id" not-null="false"  />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="UserAddress"  />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**useraddress.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping> 
    <class name="UserAddress" table="address">
        <id name="address_id" type="int" column="address_id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="addr_line1" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_1"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addr_line2" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addr_line3" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_3"/>
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="string">
            <column name="city"/>
        </property>
        <property name="zipcode" type="int">
            <column name="zipcode"/>
        </property>
        <property name="state" type="string">
            <column name="state"/>
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="string">
            <column name="country"/>
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="user_detail" class="UserDetails" fetch="select">
        <column name="user_id" not-null="false"></column>
        </many-to-one>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    //@OneToMany (mappedBy="user_details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="user_detail")
    public int user_id; //primary key
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String gender;
    private int dob;
    private int phone;
    private float experience;
    private Set<UserAddress> addr;//set name

//getters and setters created
```

**UserAddress.java**

public class UserAddress extends UserDetails {

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int address_id; //primary key
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=UserDetails.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserDetails user_detail;
        private String addr_line1;
        private String addr_line2;
        private String addr_line3;
        private String city;
        private int zipcode;
        private String state;
        private String country;
        //getters and setters created
```

I think i'm missing something in hibernate mapping part, because i can able to store other address table values except user_id. If anyone is interested to work with the complete code, i'm ready to give. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error in stacktrace?
Also you should use annotations for mapping columns & attributes.
Have you put mapping resource in hibernate configuration file?